# Discord Calendar with Google Calendar API

Tags: discord, google-calendar-api

I'm coding a calendar system where I can add calendar events from discord to my Google calendar. I got an error which I'm not able to fix.

My Code (command):

```
@bot.command()
async def add(message):
    service = get_calendar_service()
    created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
        calendarId='primary',
        text=f" ").execute()
    await message.send('{}'.format(created_event['htmlLink']))
    print(created_event['id'])
```

It creates a event but without my added time and without a title or anything else.

[image: command input]

I tried to edit some things in this line of code:

```
    created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
        calendarId='primary',
        text=f" ").execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Events: quickAdd` will use the String passed to the `text` parameter, it will create an empty event if it's blank like `text=f" "`

The solution would be for you to pass the message content to the API call, I haven't worked with Discord bots yet but based on this [official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#message) you can try doing this:

```py
@bot.command()
        async def add(message):
        service = get_calendar_service()
        created_event = service.events().quickAdd(
            calendarId='primary',
            text=message.content).execute()
        await message.send('{}'.format(created_event['htmlLink']))
        print(created_event['id'])
```

---

#### Reference:

- Google's Python Example - [Events: quickAdd](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/quickAdd#python)
- Discordpy - [Message.content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content)